# What are some general approaches to proving smoothness?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

What are some general strategies for proving that a given function $f(x)$ is smooth (continuous in all orders of derivatives)?  What properties of a function are needed to carry out a proof?

$f(x)$ and $x$ are real.

The types of functions I'm studying are not "obvious" smooth functions such as polynomials, finite sums or products of smooth functions, etc.  There is, as yet, no differential equation, or power or Fourier series.

They do have some known symmetries and a definition based on infinite sequences of discrete operations. Despite the discreteness of this definition, we suspect the result is smooth.  Other properties may be uncovered as I research further.

I know enough about $f$ to work out a delta-epsilon proof of continuity, and to prove that $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.  If I can do that, might I know enough about my function to prove smoothness?  If not, what sorts of things should I try to find out about $f(x)$?

(I don't want to say too much about the particular class of functions I'm studying; I'm just as interested in general smoothness proofs, as in applying some technique to my functions.)

Comment: Continuous and monotone is certainly not enough to prove smoothness.  I think you have to give some more information about your functions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by smooth? It typically means infinitely differentiable, but there are some other conventions.